# How can i convert an animated graph (made with ggplot2) to HTML file?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, gif, gganimate

I want to save my animated graph in an HTML file.
I have done up to this.

```
p <- animate(graph.2,duration = 20)
```

Here, 'graph.2' is my required graph. which I want to animate.
Can anyone tell me how to do after this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider adding an reproducible example for constructing the `graph.2` object (as dummy if necessary).

Comment: Thank you @manro.